# Change uploaded file name asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have such i big problem, i need to change the user uploaded file name, to some hash name, that build from the row fields of this table:
[image]

The upload proccess is clicking on the image glyphicon and then "Edit" button:
[image]

after this modal opens:
[image]

My controller is look like this:

```
<HttpPost()>
        Function UploadImage(file As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult

            Dim theImage = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream, True, True)
            Dim theImageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName)
            Dim Handler = New MongoDBHandler()
            Handler.UploadImage(theImage, theImageName)

            Return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery)
        End Function
```

My view look like:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="@Url.Action("UploadImage", "CreditCard")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" accept=".png" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-primary" name="file">
  <br>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

how can i send to the controller addition string that presents the edited file name?

Comment: Seems like you just need to swap `theImageName` with some custom string. Have you tried that?

Comment: I need to receive the name from the table via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it (assuming I understand your question)...

In your form add a new hidden input

```
<input id="fileName" type="hidden" name="fileName" value="">
```

You will need to save the fileName you want somewhere. I have just created a regular var (in js) for the example. When the edit button is clicked get the name your want from the row.

```
var uploadFileName = "";
$(".editRow").click(function() {
uploadfileName = $(this).closest("tr")   // closest row for the edit button
                   .find(".No")          // the 'No' column's td (assuming it has a class No)
                   .text();              // the text value
});
```

Then hook into the open event of your modal form and fill the hidden field with the name.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#fileName").val(uploadFileName);
});
```

Then when you submit the form you should have this fileName field too and use it to set the file's name. I can't test at the moment but I think you will just need to change your Action to this and it should all work. I can give it a try later if you still have issues.

```
 Function UploadImage(file As HttpPostedFileBase, string fileName) As ActionResult
```

Personally, I would go further and reset the fileName hidden field to an empty string everytime the modal closes to ensure a correct value is sent or none at all. Better than having a file name sent twice (but I am overly cautious :)).

Comment: the "string fileName", is automatically pass to the controller on submit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GUID (Global Unique Identifier) which are unique and can be used to name a file. Here is how you can create a GUID.

```
Dim sGUID As String
sGUID = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
```

Just add extension name at the end of your generated GUID.
This is how a GUID looks like

`9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482`

Then, change your `theImageName` with the above GUID string so, you can have a unique name.